# How can I deploy only parts of a Vue app and not the full Vue app?

Tags: vue.js, webpack

In my project, I want to deploy an individual view of my choosing to the exclusion of the other views in order to obtain the lighest possible production build. The production build will include all the things the view requires in order to function, I just need to somehow exclude all the other views (and possibly certain files the view doesn't need).

Can Webpack be configured to achieve something like this? If so, how?

Comment: Sounds interesting to me, yet what will you achieve by doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you can do it in Webpack directly, but if your goal is to simply make additional routes inaccessible in your application, in your Vue Router configuration, you can use `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'` to determine your environment and then load modules and routes conditionally. That should treeshake the unused components from your build.

```js
const getRoutes = async () => {
  let routes = []

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    const Foo = await import('./component/Foo.vue')
    routes.push({ path: '/foo', component: Foo })
  }

  routes.push({ path: '/bar', component: Bar })

  return routes
}

(async () => {
  const routes = await getRoutes()
  return new VueRouter({routes})
})()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can anyone else give a second opinion or comment on this method please? (I cannot test it currently)